# Repair a VM where the files have changed location

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have (or had) a few VM's setup in VMware Workstation (10.0.1) which worked fine. I have had a "hard disk tidy up" and have changed the paths of the VM files (config file, VHD etc) and - obviously - the VM's no longer work (file not found error).

Is there a way to tell VMware the new location of the files? At the moment all options for the VM when I right click are greyed out (All but "Open", "Favourite" and "Remove").

I know I can move the files back to their original location to be able to boot the VM but it seems odd that there is no option to change the path of the VM's files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From VMware's documentation [Move a Virtual Machine to a New Location or Host](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-FCD1EFEE-1E20-4C96-A1F0-BAC53BF728FF.html) :

> If you moved the virtual machine to a different location on the same host system, *remove the virtual machine from the library*, select **File** > **Open**, and browse to the virtual machine configuration (.vmx) file in its new location.